# Logistic regression with highly left-skewed data for the independent variable

Tags: generalized-linear-model, predictor, skewness

I am using the in-built GLM function in R to identify the model that best predict frogs' occupancy based on survey data. One of the independent variable (saturation) is highly skewed, as 36 of the 57 sites had 100% stream saturation. I used the skewness function with the moments package and I had a value of 1.73, would this render the model too shaky? I have attached the histogram for saturation and the qq residuals of the model with saturation and frogs' occupancy. I also tried to use transformations like log, power, etc. but they made the data even more skewed. I also read about reflection, but I am afraid that making too many transformation can hinder interpretation of the model.
[image][image]

Comment: But saturation is an explanatory variable right ? You are not trying to know whether saturation is explained by anything ?

Comment: Hi CaroZ, yes that's correct. Saturation is an explanatory variable for frogs' occupancy.

Answer (score 1):

First, the variable shown will have *negative* skewness as it has a long tail at the low end. I'm not sure what went wrong with your calculation. In your title, you correctly  say "left skew" but that would mean a negative value for skewnees.

Second, no form of regression requires that the variables be symmetric, much less normal. OLS regression assumes that the *errors* are normal, but even here, the assumption only relates to some applications. Logistic regression makes no such assumptions at all. But the quantile plot of the residuals would be pretty good, even for OLS regression -- here, it's just superfluous.

Third, I don't know what you mean by "shaky". If you are saying it would be sensitive to small changes, well, you could try it out. Add noise or other things to the IV and see what happens to the model.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the suggestion. You are right, the skewness value is -1.48.

Answer (score 1):

For an issue like this, I would suggest collapsing values of the saturation variable into three categories $k=3$:

$1-\textrm{Saturation}\leq 50\%$;

$2-50\%>\textrm{Saturation}\leq 95\%$;

$3-\textrm{Saturation}>95\%$

Then, generate two $(k-1)$ new dummy variables that are coded as follows:

$X_{sat,2}=\begin{cases} 0 \textrm{ if } \textrm{Saturation}\leq 50\%\\
1 \textrm{ if } 50\%>\textrm{Saturation}\leq 95\% \end{cases}$

$X_{sat,3}=\begin{cases} 0 \textrm{ if } \textrm{Saturation}\leq 50\%\\
1 \textrm{ if } \textrm{Saturation}>95\% \end{cases}$

There will never be a cases when both dummy variables are equal to one.

Include the two dummy variables in your model above to either (a) control(adjust) for the effect of saturation if it's a nuisance factor -- i.e. a factor whose regression coeffs you're not so interested in, but rather needs to be used as an adjustment in the model; or (b) provide coeff values (slopes) and significance as a main study factor.

The rationale for doing the above is that values of a continuously-scaled variable don't always present a smooth distribution, dispersion, skewness, and could be multimodal, very jagged, etc. $\rightarrow$ "messy."

The other issue is that the underlying dose-response or dose-behavior relationship is not always known, and therefore collapsing into groups may be seen as a step that doesn't decrease informativeness.

From a pattern recognition point of view, it never hurts to develop the experience to look at a histogram and say "I really see three clusters of values of saturation: a low group, intermediate group, and a high group."

Comment: Hi wijktrs, sorry I forgot to mention that I also tried this method. I used the very same categories that you mentioned and I had a skewness value of -0.88. I was evaluating whether using saturation as raw data or categories because raw saturation+psi was the best model whereas categorical saturation+psi had higher AIC than psi itself.

Comment: Skewness does not apply to binarized dummy variables, which can be created to break up (to avoid) the highly left-skewed continuous variable.  Is the Saturation variable a variable you are investigating for its effect on e.g. odds ratio or yhat(0,1) prediction, or simply to adjust the model by Saturation as a confounder or nuisance variable?  In my experience, once I binarized a highly skewed variable, I would probably never to back to using the original continuous variable, since it is not really very smooth -- the histogram is very jumpy, with spikes and holes.

Comment: Moreover, I would not focus on model results, fit, or significance for the original skewed variable, once I made the two dummy variables.   In other words, once I do something like this for a variable transformation after noticing a sparse, messy histogram for a continuous variable, I never look back.   The original variable is a problem from my perspective, so I "engineer around the problem."

Comment: Many journal statistical reviewers would also read what you did in the methods write up, which would simply be called "binarizing a problematic continuous variable," and probably think there's nothing wrong with doing that.   What happens with the results is your responsibility.  Your variable is no different from a protein expression variable for which e.g. 50-75% of patients have zero expression (b/c of genetics) and the other have non-zero values.  Why would you input a variable with 50-75% zero values into a model?

Comment: You just happen to have about 60-70% near 100% saturation, with the rest distributed very sparsely with much lower saturation values - it's not even a distribution. So, same question, why would you input that variable into a model? Another probelm is 60-70% of the near 100% saturation values are invariant, i.e., don't vary or change (zero s.d.), so these values are non-informative.   They're informative if you use grouped analysis however.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Answering your question, I am investigating the effect of stream saturation on frogs' occupancy (0,1).